# Boot 16.04.3 from PCIe USB 3 card without bios support

Tags: 16.04, grub2, usb, live-usb

**I have read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/220364/551485) which might make this question a duplicate:**

The linked question is for 12.04, which is quite old, and I wanted to see if there was a newer, more preferred option.

**Situation**: I have a desktop machine, about 8 years old, which does not have any USB 3.0 ports. I added a USB 3.0 PICe card specifically so I could run my entire system off an external USB 3.0 drive without slowing down to USB 2.0 speeds.

Sadly, when I went into my bios to set my boot drive to the USB drive, which was now connected to the new USB 3.0 port, I could not select the drive. It seems my computer's bios is too old to recognize the newer card and I do not see any updates from the mainboard's manufacturer.

Once I boot into my drive (while connected to a USB 2.0 port) I can easily access anything connected to the USB 3.0 ports. So, I'm hopeful that there is an answer waiting to be found.

**My question**: Is there a way I can boot from something like a LiveUSB stick but just use that to transfer the boot over to the USB drive connected to the 3.0 ports? So, I would only need the LiveUSB (or other option) just to get my existing drive to boot up normally.

Comment: You can try chainloading according to the following link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Chainloading