# Where to find full documentation for menuentry used in grub's 40_custom file?

Tags: grub2, documentation

In a potential answer (a comment, actually) to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/995459/551485), there is reference to [chainloading using the 40_custom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Chainloading) file in grub2. The sample given on the link for chainloading does not work. I suspect it is because of uniqueness in my drive (encrypted, ext3/ext4).

I have been unable to find the documentation on the **menuitem** entry used in the **40_custom** file. I see there are multiple options for referencing the drive (relative position like **set root='(hd1)'** vs uuid like **set root=UUID=XXXX-YYYY**).

Anyway, I'm trying to find a page somewhere which documents the options for a menuentry in 40_custom.

Comment: Maybe this might help:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, perhaps https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Device-syntax see also https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/

Comment: @Panther Thanks, this is the kind of detail I was missing.